# How can I "un-merge" faces from a continuous mesh?

Tags: modeling, faces

How can I separate a set of faces from a continuous mesh in Edit mode, without moving the selected faces to another object? I'd like to keep the faces within the same object, if possible.

Comment: Select the edges of the faces you wan to separate and press V to **rip** them.

Comment: I've tried this method, but it gives an error message saying "Cannot rip selected faces." The selected faces are complete faces with 4 vertices each. I can't even get it to work with single 4-vertex faces. It *does* work with single vertices but that would be a lot of work. Blender 2.76

Comment: Then use **Split** the shortcut is **Y**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the face you want to disconnect from your mesh and press **<kbd>Y</kbd>** to **[Split](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#split)** the face.

[image]

Comment: Wasn't the shortcut __V__ before?

Comment: @someonewithpc **V** is to rip, **Y** to split. to rip yo have to leave at least one connected edge. Split will let you separate a whole face.

Comment: @someonewithpc more info: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html